# Sails.js count where

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to count a subset of a collection, where the subset determined by an attribute. The code is:

```
User.count()
    .where({attribute:{'<':10}})
    .exec(function(err, users){
        callback(err, users);
    });
```

`User.count` by itself will return the total collection count, but putting in any WHERE clauses seems to consistently return 0. Does the `count` method not support WHERE clauses?

NB I'm using the Mongodb adapter both for this collection and by default. The 'attribute' exists on all models and is populated with numerical data (above and below 10).

Answer (score 16):

.count() now supports criteria, too. Take a look at the docs: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/waterline/models/count.md

In a nutshell:

```
User.count({name:'Flynn'}).exec(function countCB(err, found){
  console.log('There are '+found+' users called "Flynn".');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use User.countBy( criteria , [callback] ) in sails v0.10.0-rc4 :)
[Model Methods countBy](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/ModelMethods/.countBy.html)

Comment: The method `.countBy()` is actually deprecated and should not be used.